# How can I remove 'Name' and 'dtype' from Dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a python script that reads from excel, does some calculations and returns some values that I have to write back to excel. I have constructed an output dataframe (using multiple lists, put into a dictionary and converted to pandas Dataframe) inside a function. The function is supposed to return the dataframe. It does this perfectly but some elements of the dataframe comes along with stuffs such as 'Name: 0, dtype: float64'. I have to write this dataframe to an excel workbook. The written values in excel cell also has Name, dtype attached to it. How can I get only values in dataframe (and excel obviously) with Name and dtype suppressed. I have tried many stuffs but with no luck.

*here is a sample output for one of the column as with above situation*

```
ECL as % of exposure
10    0.031125
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

> here, the only thing I want is 0.031125

*the actual code is very long so here is the snippet that should define above situation*

```
    d = {
        'Stage': n_stageName,
        'Year After Origination': n_yearAfterOrigination,
        'Management Overlay': n_mgmt_overlay,
        'PD curve ID': n_pd_curveID,
        'LGD': n_LGD,
        'ECL': n_ECL,
        'FLI Adj ECL': n_FLI_adj_ECL,
        'EIR': n_EIR,
        'ECL (JMD)': n_ECL_JMD,
        'FLI Adj ECL (JMD)': n_FLI_adj_ECL_JMD,
        'Exposure': n_Exposure,
        'ECL as % of exposure': n_ECL_as_percent_of_Exposure
    }

    output_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    return output_df
```

Comment: How are you writing the dataframe to Excel? That looks like the Python string representation of the dataframe. I've never had this problem when using the `df.to_excel` method. It's hard to know what's going on without a MWE.

Comment: (you might want to use index=None when you write to excel though)

Comment: link to py script
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3mjjxaf3vddz1cj/Amortization_revised.py?dl=0



Zogroth
here are the linkslink to excel_source
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jugl78xpxbuil9neg3fkt/ECL-Consultant-Data-Sample.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=2jbpe6dknlam0otx7tvdfr5lf

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the values from the series, then `output_df.values` should do the trick. This will return a numpy array of the values.